# Space appears when reduce the window size?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet, footer

I'm testing my website and there is a problem that I don't know how to solve in the footer section. The problem is that when I try to reduce the window size of the browser, at one particular point, the footer leaves the space from the right corner and when I increase the window size back, the footer extends back to normal. I also provide the image as you can see below

and this is my html and also the CSS for this section

```
<div class="footer"> <!-- Declare Section -->
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;"> <!-- COntainer Box -->
    <div class="span11">
        <p class="copyright">Copyright @2013 by Lunarmind Inc. All rights       reserved</p>
    </div>
    <div class="adminlinkcontainer">
        <a class="adminlink" href="admin.php">admin</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is CSS

```
.footer {
background-color:#383838;
width:100%;
height:50px;
margin-top:50px;
}

.copyright {
color:#fff;
margin-top:16px;
margin-left:6px;
}
```

Comment: Where's the image? A URL would be better, though.

Comment: A URL is required in order to fix this issue.

Comment: This is the url. I am sorry for the late reply
http://flourishtech.freevar.com/

Comment: The only thing I can notice, is that at a small enough width the text isnt centered anymore, because the whole site has reached its minimum width. Is this what you are talking about? If not: What browser do you use? And where's the image showing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `min-width: 1100px` set on your footer. Get rid of that and that should solve your problem.